# Discord bot- type error expected token to be str, received class none instead

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, replit

I'm trying to write a bot in discord. At first I had this error: type error expected token to be str, received class none instead.
But after adding these lines-

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('token.env')
```

where token.env is the name of the file containing my token information for the bot. Now it works correctly.

Anyone who wants to try and do so too can try and use this template.
Here is my code:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('token.env')

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents, help_command=None)

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

print(os.getenv('TOKEN') is None)
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

here is what I get when I try to run it:

```
True
2022-08-18 08:59:59 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "/home/runner/MyLibrary/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/MyLibrary/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/MyLibrary/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/MyLibrary/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 577, in login
    raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__!r} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received <class 'NoneType'> instead
```

Comment: There should be a way to load the envs i python. Try dotenv or something to load the env file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not well versed with Discord bots, but usually, the practice is for the environment file to be just named `.env`.

Anyway, the issue is that `os.getenv('TOKEN')` is getting nothing, because environment variable `TOKEN` does not exist.

Just make sure you named or put the environment variable correctly.

You can also set the default to something else via a second parameter in the `getenv()` function: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-osgetenv-method-in-python